# NDK ネイティブライブラリからTEXTRELの削除

Tags: android, c++

android23以降はTEXTRELを含むネイティブライブラリを読み込めなくなったみたいです。
`System.loadLibrary()`にて次の例外が発生します。

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError
dlopen failed: "libXXX.so" has text relocations 
(https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#Text-Relocations-Enforced-for-API-level-23)
```

私はlibXXX.so本体と、それに含まれる外部ライブラリにTEXTRELが含まれるかを次のコマンドで調べたところ、
その両方でTEXTRELが含まれている事がわかりました。
`readelf -a {so PATH} | grep TEXTREL`

TEXTRELを削除したいのですがAndroid NDKの場合どのようなオプションを付ければよろしいのでしょうか？
（調べたところ　LOCALC_FLAGS := -fPIC　をつければいい気はしましたが改善されず…）

今回のようにTEXTRELが含まれるのがコンパイル済みの外部ライブラリ（.so）等の場合、
これらをリンクして生成したライブラリでもTEXTRELがついてしまうのでしょうか？
そうならば、外部ライブラリ自体を再コンパイルしないといけないですか？

AndroidNDKはandroid-ndk-r9dを使用しており、
古いcocosを使っている関係でNDKを新しいものに変えるのは難しいです。

また、アプリ配布先よりtargetSDKを26にするように指示されているため
targetSDKを23以下にするのも対応できません。

Comment: ターゲットアーキテクチャは何でしょうか？TEXTRELセクションが含まれるということは32bit(`armeabi-v7a`/`x86`)と推測されますが、[GooglePlayが要求する64bit対応](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)ができないとそもそもアプリ公開不可能です。（GooglePlay以外の配布であれば可能ですが...）

Comment: armeabi-v7aです。ストアはgooglePlayではありません。32ビットだけの問題なんですね！64ビットへの変更も使ってるライブラリの関係で困難ですが（現状でライブラリに64ビットがない）64ビットにして解決することをもう一度試したいと思います。64ビットで発生しないとわかたっただけでも選択肢が増えました！貴重な情報ありがとうございました！